The lower bound of Green function in small ball
Let $G$ be a Green function on $B_r=B_{r}(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 3$, namely,
$$
G\left( x,y \right) =\begin{cases}
 \Gamma \left( \left| x-y \right| \right) -\Gamma \left( \frac{\left| x \right|}{r}\left| y-\bar{x} \right| \right) ,&  x\ne 0\\
 \Gamma \left( \left| y \right| \right) -\Gamma \left( r \right) ,&  x=0\\
\end{cases}.
$$
Here, $\bar{x}=\frac{r^2}{\left| x \right|^2}x$ and
$$
\Gamma \left( x-y \right) =\frac{1}{n\left( n-2 \right) \omega _n}\left| x-y \right|^{2-n}.
$$
In a paper, the author wrote that there exists a constant $c$ such that
$$
G\left( x,y \right) \ge cr^{2-n}\quad \forall x,y\in B_{r/2}\left( 0 \right) .
$$
I don't know how to check it. In fact, I can only obtain this estimate in $B_{r/4}(0)$, or some balls that smaller than $B_{r/2}(0)$.


By rescaling, you can restrict to the case $r = 1$.

It's a general fact for Green's functions that $G(x,y) > 0$ for all $x,y$ in the domain. In this case, this inequality can be checked directly, as $G(x,y) > 0$ reduces to $|y-x| < |x| \cdot |y-\bar{x}|$, which is equivalent to $(1-|x|^2)(1-|y|^2) > 0$ by squaring both sides.

The function $G(x,y)$ attains its minimum on the compact set $\overline{B}_{1/2} \times \overline{B}_{1/2}$, and by point 2 this minimum is positive, i.e. $G(x,y) \ge c > 0$ for all $x,y \in \overline{B}_{1/2}$. This can be proved analogously to Weierstrass' theorem on extrema of continuous functions (in fact, $G$ is an upper semicontinuous function).


